# PHP: Adjust regex to add a character at the end of every word

Tags: php, regex

I have following regex:

```
// Before: "Foo Bar Test";
$str = preg_replace( "/(^| )(\w)/", '$1+$2', $str );
// After: "+Foo +Bar +Test";
```

Is it possible to add the char "*" at the end of every word?

The result I am looking for is:

```
// +Foo* +Bar* +Test*
```

Is it possible to do it in the same regex? Or do I have to use a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$str = preg_replace( "/(^| )(\w+)\b/", '$1+$2*', $str );

echo "$str\n";
//=> +Foo* +Bar* +Test*
```

Making 2nd captured group as `(\w+)` will make it capture full word and putting `*` after `$2` will place `*` at right place.

**PS:** You can also use **lookbehind assertion**:

```
$str = preg_replace( "/(?<= |^)(\w+)\b/", '+$1*', $str );
```

to get the same output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! This is working perfect! :)

Comment: You can *probably* simplify this to `preg_replace('/\w+/', '+$0*', $str)`